# How to get the column sums in row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table `Expense` where monthly expense is stored.
Now I want to get a result like "output". Here ID will be set according to the month sequence hence December will get 12.

How can I achieve that? I tried Unpivot but cant achieve it. [image]

Comment: Post sample data instead of screeenshot of an excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
select tt.id, sum(tt.monval) as TotalExpense
from Expense t cross apply
     ( values (1, January), (2, February), (3, March) ) tt(id, monval)
group by tt.id;
```

Comment: what is mean by tt?

Comment: Thanks, but,What is 'Id'? I have only the table "Expense" as existing. "Output" table I want to be generated

Comment: @RameshRajendran. . . `tt` is a alias same as `table t`.

Comment: @BlackCat. . . `id` is a unique sequence for month header which is used for grouping purpose to generate the `TotalExpense`.

Comment: Is it alias or function??  because `tt(...)` looks like function as there is no space between `( id,moval)`

Comment: can you please post the solution according to my given names? I am getting error :(

Comment: @RameshRajendran. . . I have used `values` construct that generates the table with name of `tt` & with column name of `id, monval`.